# Windows 10 - App store update history

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-store-app

My Windows 10 apps update automatically. I prefer this.

1. Is there a way to see the history of what apps were updated, and on what dates? OR at least the most recent ones that were updated?
2. Is there a way to see a change log of the app history? For example, in Android app store they have a section that shows the most recent changes to the application, If the developer chooses to enter it. I can't find anything similar on Windows PC apps that are installed.

Thanks!

Comment: Windows 10 does not have this feature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell by inspecting the items in your library from the Store app

- Open Windows 10 Store app
- Click on your user photo next to the search box on the top of the app
- Select "My Library"
- Click "Show all" under "App" or "Games"

Listed will be the date the app was last updated (even if the app is not installed on the computer). You can click each item and go to the store page. If the developer has provided "What's new in this version", it'll show.

Not the greatest solution. I'd like some sort of notification in the Action Center, personally.

Comment: The only thing missing is the Windows Apps (maps, photos, groove, etc.) that are updated via the Windows Store, but doesn't appear in your library. I don't find it very consistent, and you don't usually know when they are being updated.

Comment: @LeoLozes I've been watching the list of apps since I posted this answer, and you are right. I've also noticed two more anomalies. Some apps always show as updated on the current date. The two for me are Twitter and Candy Crush Saga. I've never installed the latter (it's one of the games Windows 10 will promote to you).

Comment: It doesn't show up in "My Library" anymore, but it does show up in "Downloads and Updates"... as long as the app in question was one of the last 9 to update.

Comment: All app versions & last update dates are shown in My Library still on Windows 1803. "Downloads and Updates" is limited to the last 11 applications.

Comment: This approach is only useful if you've had the app installed long enough to get an update. On the other hand, I'm looking at an app in the store I haven't yet installed, and want to know when the developer last updated the app. There's a "What's new in this version" section, but that doesn't have a date nor a version number.