# How to view update history of an application installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, docker

0

I have an application installed on my Windows 10 machine. There's been some updates on that application since it's been installed.

I'm now looking to see when's this application been updated-- the history of it. Is there a way to do this? Google shows all Windows' own update history, but this isn't even a Microsoft app. Control Panel shows no hints, either.

The "app" i mention above is Docker. But i'm looking for a general solution/also, if there is.

Application history and data usage history of a Windows Phone 8 Application says "no" but don't wanna miss out-- an old thread.

TIA.

//----------------------------

This Q is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585276/how-to-view-update-history-of-an-application-installed-on-windows.

Saw [Windows 10 - App store update history](https://superuser.com/questions/953894/windows-10-app-store-update-history), but that doesn't help. Microsoft Store is showing only Microsoft apps.

Comment: Most applications leave a log file somewhere. Search Google: (your app name) log file location?

Comment: Although @Moab is not wrong, MANY applications do nothing of the sort.  Docker is one of them as far as I know.  It is up to each application vendor to keep track of this themselves.  Even MSI (Microsoft installer) doesn't do this internally when a previous MSI gets updated.  Moreover, many installers WIPE the previous versions and all traces before laying down the new version.

Comment: As @SeñorCMasMas states, it's up to the app itself. And even Window update history is deleted if *dism /resetbase* has been used. However, almost all app updates present the user with a UAC dialog, asking *permission* to make changes to the system, so you'd likely have seen that prompt  (though I don't know if Docker bypasses that).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas write this as an ans and i'll accept as yours was the first ans

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thx for confirming. can't upvote your comment-- i haven't enough points i think.